# How to remove the undefined/null from array inside the array in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
DATA = [{
    application: [{
        name: 'Room1'
    },{
        name: 'Room2'
    },{
        name: 'Room3'
    },{
        name: 'Room4'
    },{
        name: 'Room5'
    }, , undefined, null, null],
    name: 'Batch 1',
    date: '2020-10-20'
}]
```

What I'm trying to do here is to remove the `undefined/null` from the array.
the undefined/null should be remove.

output should be like this:

```
 [{
    application: [{
        name: 'Room1'
    },{
        name: 'Room2'
    },{
        name: 'Room3'
    },{
        name: 'Room4'
    },{
        name: 'Room5'
    }],
    name: 'Batch 1',
    date: '2020-10-20'
}]
```

it will remove the null or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to keep only `!!item` (i.e. not-null, not-undefined, not-empty, not-false and not-zero items).

```js
let DATA = [{
  application: [{
    name: 'Room1'
  }, {
    name: 'Room2'
  }, {
    name: 'Room3'
  }, {
    name: 'Room4'
  }, {
    name: 'Room5'
  }, , undefined, null, null],
  name: 'Batch 1',
  date: '2020-10-20'
}];
DATA[0].application = DATA[0].application.filter(item => !!item);
console.log(DATA);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
DATA = [{
    application: [{
        name: 'Room1'
    },{
        name: 'Room2'
    },{
        name: 'Room3'
    },{
        name: 'Room4'
    },{
        name: 'Room5'
    }, , undefined, null, null],
    name: 'Batch 1',
    date: '2020-10-20'
}]

DATA[0].application = DATA[0].application.filter(i=> i);
console.log(DATA)
```